# Visual Studio erroneously showing that name does not exist in current context

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022, and for a few different versions (of 2022) I have noticed that the symbol parsing (or whatever is responsible for this error message) is performing fairly poorly. I have two projects - one is a c++20 project, and the other is a managed .net 6 WinUI3 project. Both suffer from this really annoying issue where I get "The name xyz does not exist in the current context" in my editor, even when the symbol is absolutely defined and the build will succeed.

I know this is purely a VS error and not something wrong with my code. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding but to no avail. Is there any way to make the symbol parser realize it's mistake?

I am using a pretty standard installation of community edition. I don't have any plugins.

This is also happening on my work AND home machine - which don't even share the same Microsoft account associated with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple days of this highly annoying VS issue, through multiple IDE and even machine restarts, I was able to fix it by right-clicking the project and selecting unload, then right-clicking again to re-load.